# How to set a background drawable on a clicked GridView item in Android?

Tags: android, selecteditem, android-gridview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `GridView` with a bunch of icons and I need to select one. And by select I mean:

- I need the drawable id to store into a database (so I can access it later)
- I need to draw some kind of visual cue on the grid to let the user know which icon is currently selected

I found this:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f08a58167dbaa8c8

So I guess `setSelection` is out of the picture and I can't use it to select the icon itself nor draw the visual cue. I know the grid item position in the `onItemClickListener` and I can save it as a private class variable. My biggest problem is drawing that visual cue.

How can I achieve that? How can I draw a visual cue on the clicked item and if the user clicks different items, to "undraw" that visual cue and redraw it in the new item?

Comment: i'd like to see the answer to this. I believe, that if you want some kind of selection cue, you need a focusable object. However, with a focusable object, attaching OnItemClickListener to the GridView does not work. Rather, you must individually attach an OnClickListener to each item at getView() in the adapter.

Comment: I assume that attaching `OnClickListener` to each item is not really viable, or is it? That could be a possible solution, so if you are up to it, you can do a proper answer below. I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After tackling with this for a couple of hours I think I finally found the solution I was looking for. Although the answers are barely related, the initial edits on Ian solution helped me find this solution :)

I'm not going to explain everything I did, I think it's pretty self explanatory. Just a few remarks:

- First I tried `view.Invalidate()` and `view.postInvalidate()` instead of `iconAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but neither worked. The documentation stated that the invalidate methods only "asked" to redraw the view "when possible".
- I was looking for a simpler solution than to merge two drawables. For instance, draw the icon on the `ImageView` background and the visual cue as the image. For some strange reason, the visual cue started to show randomly all over the other icons when the `GridView` was scrolled. I don't understand why, but the idea of a visual cue on top of a background image makes perfect sense to me and `ImageView` allows that, no need for that extra merge method. However, I couldn't make it work without it...

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private GridView mGridViewIcon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mGridViewIcon = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview_icon);
        mGridViewIcon.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(this));

        mGridViewIcon.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                IconAdapter iconAdapter = (IconAdapter)parent.getAdapter();

                iconAdapter.setSelectedItemPosition(position);
                iconAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**IconAdapter.java**

```
public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    private int mIconSize;
    private Context mContext;

    public IconAdapter(Context context) {
        mThumbIds = AppHelper.ICON_SET.keySet().iterator().next();
        mIconSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.default_icon_size);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if(convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        if(mSelectedPosition == position) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mergeDrawableLayers(mThumbIds[position],
                    R.drawable.ic_note_selected_mark));
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemPosition(int position) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
    }

    private Drawable mergeDrawableLayers(int background, int overlay) {
        Drawable[] drawableLayers = new Drawable[2];

        drawableLayers[0] = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(background);
        drawableLayers[1] = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(overlay);

        return new LayerDrawable(drawableLayers);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that if you want some kind of selection cue, you need a focusable object. However, with a focusable object (such as a Button), attaching OnItemClickListener to the GridView does not work (if i remember correctly). Rather, you must individually attach an OnClickListener to each item at getView() in the adapter.

Adapter:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            button = new Button(mContext);
            // set layout params (make sure its GridView.layoutParams)
            // and other stuff

        } 
        else {
            button = (Button) convertView;
        }

        button.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]); // mThumbIds hold Resource Ids
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           onClick(View v) {
             // store directly to database here, or send it with the activity with sharedPreferences (below)

             // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
             // All objects are from android.context.Context
             SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", 0);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
             editor.putInt("button_id", mThumbIds[position]);

             // Commit the edits!
             editor.commit();
           } 
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

On Activity Side, save button onClickListener:

```
onClick(View v) {
// Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", 0);
       int id = settings.getInt("button_id", -1);

       // now safe all stuff to database
}
```

There may be details missing because a Button is focusable, but i think this should do. Also ,  you will achieve the selection by using a .xml defined selector resource. That, however, should be addressed in a separate question.

Edit 1:
 Actually now that i think about it, i'm not sure if a drawable .xml (the selector) can have an ID. I'll have to implement this at home later on and try it.

Edit 2:
 I added the sharedPreference part

Edit 3:
 Added activity side querying of sharedPreference.

Comment: I see what you mean know, I'm just not sure about one thing. The GridView is just one element of my Activity, I have other stuff there too, like EditText widgets. Then there's a button which is the one responsible for storing all the data into the database, including the id from the GridView item. I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: so you only want to store the information with a "save" button? This will make the answer just beyond the scope of the question, i believe. Perhaps you can use a sharedPreference to save the item id, then query the preference in the activity.

Comment: The "store the information" part is not relevant at all, what I meant was that I needed the position of the GridView item clicked stored in some variable in the Activity holding that GridView. If I have that, the save is trivial (I assume, I'm learning Android as I go and haven't yet reached that part yet). But your previous answer (before the 2nd edit) gave me a few ideas which I have been working on these past hours. I think I've found a solution for my problem, I'll post my own answer when get I the chance in an hour or so.

Comment: well just query the sharedPreference in your activity. It is very easy.

Comment: I don't like to do things that I don't understand. And honestly, it seems too much just to store an integer.

Comment: alas, the easiest would be to use an onitemclicklistener then, and abandon the selection requirement.

Comment: I think I finally did it... Going to post my answer in a few minutes!